# yii2 translations stopped working

Tags: yii2, internationalization

I have changed nothing in my config file, and maybe because of an update or I don't know, I realized that translations doesn't work anymore.

```
'components' => [
    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            '*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@app/messages',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'yii' => 'yii.php',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

I have tried with `'*' =>`, `'app' =>`, `'app*' =>`, nothing is working, and I've tried to search but found nothing relevant. There are no error messages, except a warning for rbac-admin:

> warning: The message file for category 'rbac-admin' does not exist: .../vendor/mdmsoft/messages/de/rbac-admin.php

however it's there, but it doesn't really matter at the moment.

Can you please point me to the right direction? Thanks a lot!

Comment: How did you know its not working? I mean maybe its a problem with locale for example. If locale is set to something that wont need translation then its normal to see no translations

Comment: I know that's not working, because it was working before. Everything was translated to german, now it's everything english. I haven't changed anything, locale is `de` as before. Source language is not set but if I set it to `en-US` makes no difference.

Comment: can you use print_r(Yii::$app->language);die; anywhere where you expect to get German language. This will allow us to know the langauge of the locale at implementation

Comment: print_r(Yii::$app->language); = de

Comment: This means that this is the language is set to. If you tried setting the language there to en-US, you'll get things in English. You can try this, and if it worked, all you need to do is just trace where is the language set in application, and make sure that the language is set in some global place when the app is accessed

Comment: `'language' => 'de'` is set in web.php. I get always everything in english, even if I set it to `de`, that's the problem.

Comment: there must be something with Yii2. In the same view, I have two buttons `Yii::t('yii', 'Edit')` and `Yii::t('yii', 'Delete')`, **Edit** is not translated, **Delete** is, however both can be found in `...messages/de/yii.php`

Comment: meanwhile, problem solved?

Comment: not really. I keep the framework updated, but no change.